# How to get my Image Uploaded to Server in Android(Volley)?

Tags: android

> Here is how i passed to Volley
>   Here is select Image function from gallery

```
    private void selectImage(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(intent,IMG_REQUEST);
    Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString();
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMG_REQUEST);
}
```

> here is onActivity Result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==IMG_REQUEST && resultCode== RESULT_OK && data!=null){

            Uri path= data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),path);
                img_below.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                img_below.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

> This is how i compressed the Image

```
private String ImageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgBytes= byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```

> LogCat response

```
E/MyImage: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAVwCAIAAAAmDnhtAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4nMy925IkOY4lCFDVPDKydkZaZEb6/39vH7ZXtmsqM8NNSewDCBA3qplHZlU3JcRDTZUEQRAED3hF/B8AAIjAgWg+6Bt9TwRAAM1FaG0+ICIRcTQlYoNE2xPn3FM0NNHQs0cEo8iqyFr+TSZDIIJ2QGtwHHAcDdtoreHMrJ3neZ4nIg4JAEADxxgUA4znQURjDCIgzGwgIkJDAGA+qA8AU/wUWDhahPMBiIBwIOIAHGPQAM5RhWXjAwIiEEHvQANag9YW5TFmpiu+yRcIE
```

Comment: imageString = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAVwCAIAAAAmDnhtAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAgAElEQVR4nMy925IkOY4lCFDVPDKydkZaZEb6/39vH7ZXtmsqM8NNSewDCBA3qplHZlU3JcRDTZUEQRAED3hF/B8AAIjAgWg+6Bt9TwRAAM1FaG0+ICIRcTQlYoNE2xPn3FM0NNHQs0cEo8iqyFr+TSZDIIJ2QGtwHHAcDdtoreHMrJ3neZ4nIg4JAEADxxgUA4znQURjDCIgzGwgIkJDAGA+qA8AU/wUWDhahPMBiIBwIOIAHGPQAM5RhWXjAwIiEEHvQANag9YW5TFmpiu+yRcIE'//decode base64 string-image
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);

Comment: are You Sure, because i tried it too !

Comment: do want to create an a jpg file....?

Comment: yes, it may be jpg or png

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691333/9924931

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send file you can use below code to send Volley multipart request .

create java class name VolleyMultipartRequest and paste this code in it ;

```
public class VolleyMultipartRequest extends Request<NetworkResponse> {
    private final String twoHyphens = "--";
    private final String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    private final String boundary = "apiclient-" + System.currentTimeMillis();

    private Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> mListener;
    private Response.ErrorListener mErrorListener;
    private Map<String, String> mHeaders;

    /**
     * Default constructor with predefined header and post method.
     *
     * @param url           request destination
     * @param headers       predefined custom header
     * @param listener      on success achieved 200 code from request
     * @param errorListener on error http or library timeout
     */
    public VolleyMultipartRequest(String url, Map<String, String> headers,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
        this.mHeaders = headers;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with option method and default header configuration.
     *
     * @param method        method for now accept POST and GET only
     * @param url           request destination
     * @param listener      on success event handler
     * @param errorListener on error event handler
     */
    public VolleyMultipartRequest(int method, String url,
                                  Response.Listener<NetworkResponse> listener,
                                  Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.mListener = listener;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return (mHeaders != null) ? mHeaders : super.getHeaders();
    }

    @Override
    public String getBodyContentType() {
        return "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        try {
            // populate text payload
            Map<String, String> params = getParams();
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                textParse(dos, params, getParamsEncoding());
            }

            // populate data byte payload
            Map<String, DataPart> data = getByteData();
            if (data != null && data.size() > 0) {
                dataParse(dos, data);
            }

            // close multipart form data after text and file data
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            return bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Custom method handle data payload.
     *
     * @return Map data part label with data byte
     * @throws AuthFailureError
     */
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() throws AuthFailureError {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<NetworkResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            return Response.success(
                    response,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        mListener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    /**
     * Parse string map into data output stream by key and value.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param params           string inputs collection
     * @param encoding         encode the inputs, default UTF-8
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void textParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, String> params, String encoding) throws IOException {
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                buildTextPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + encoding, uee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Parse data into data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle file attachment
     * @param data             loop through data
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void dataParse(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, Map<String, DataPart> data) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, DataPart> entry : data.entrySet()) {
            buildDataPart(dataOutputStream, entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write string data into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle string parsing
     * @param parameterName    name of input
     * @param parameterValue   value of input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildTextPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, String parameterName, String parameterValue) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + parameterName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parameterValue + lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Write data file into header and data output stream.
     *
     * @param dataOutputStream data output stream handle data parsing
     * @param dataFile         data byte as DataPart from collection
     * @param inputName        name of data input
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void buildDataPart(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, DataPart dataFile, String inputName) throws IOException {
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" +
                inputName + "\"; filename=\"" + dataFile.getFileName() + "\"" + lineEnd);
        if (dataFile.getType() != null && !dataFile.getType().trim().isEmpty()) {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: " + dataFile.getType() + lineEnd);
        }
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        ByteArrayInputStream fileInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(dataFile.getContent());
        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dataOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    }

    /**
     * Simple data container use for passing byte file
     */
    public class DataPart {
        private String fileName;
        private byte[] content;
        private String type;

        /**
         * Default data part
         */
        public DataPart() {
        }

        /**
         * Constructor with data.
         *
         * @param name label of data
         * @param data byte data
         */
        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor with mime data type.
         *
         * @param name     label of data
         * @param data     byte data
         * @param mimeType mime data like "image/jpeg"
         */
        public DataPart(String name, byte[] data, String mimeType) {
            fileName = name;
            content = data;
            type = mimeType;
        }

        /**
         * Getter file name.
         *
         * @return file name
         */
        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Setter file name.
         *
         * @param fileName string file name
         */
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        /**
         * Getter content.
         *
         * @return byte file data
         */
        public byte[] getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        /**
         * Setter content.
         *
         * @param content byte file data
         */
        public void setContent(byte[] content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        /**
         * Getter mime type.
         *
         * @return mime type
         */
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        /**
         * Setter mime type.
         *
         * @param type mime type
         */
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
}
```

after that you should send multipart request just like that :

```
private void SendFile(String feedback) {
    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            MainActivity.URL,

            response -> {
            },
            error -> {
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
            Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
            // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
            // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
        params.put("picture_file", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", GetByteFromBitmap(bt), "image/jpeg"));


            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(multipartRequest);
}
```

and for getting byte from file use code below :

```
    private byte[] GetByteFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
       // bitmap.recycle();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Comment: can u please elaborate a little bit Pls

Answer (score 0):

Add the Permission first

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Call the method

```
SaveImageToSDCard(photo,photo_id);  //Photo Base64 encode image and photo_id is name of image
```

Finally add this method in your code

```
void SaveImageToSDCard(String Image, String photo_id){
```

try{

```
 byte[] imageBytes=Base64.decode(Image, Base64.DEFAULT);
     InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
     Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

     String mBaseFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Clubs/"+club_id;

     if (!new File(mBaseFolderPath).exists()) {
        new File(mBaseFolderPath).mkdir();
     }
     String mFilePath = mBaseFolderPath + "/" + photo_id + ".jpg";

     File file = new File(mFilePath);

     FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);

     if (!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
       }

     image.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

     is.close();
     image.recycle();

     stream.flush();
     stream.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.v("SaveFile",""+e);
}
```

}